# Data from Same Column Joined in Two Different Ways

Tags: sybase, sybase-sql-anywhere, alias

In the following sybase query I would like to pull the vendor column twice: the first time I would like to pull the vendor associated with the ReceiveWorksheet table by associating it with a key RCW_VEN_FK, and I then would like to pull from the same table again but this time associating it with the StockInventoryLocal table by the key SIL_VEN_FK_Default.  The goal is to pull the data into two different columns - one which will show the default vendor and one which will show the vendor associated with the receiving worksheet.

I've been looking for quite some time on how to accomplish this.  The first time I received an error that the item was already created (when trying to simply pull from the Vendor table twice), I then tried with aliasing and was unable to accomplish it in that manner.

Does anyone have a suggestion or a resource on how to pull this information from the Vendor table twice and associate it with different keys in different tables and have it populate as two different columns?

```
ALTER VIEW "ecrs"."00_Test3_BD"( /* view_column_name, ... */ )
AS
SELECT "ecrs"."Vendor"."VEN_Code",
"ecrs"."Vendor"."VEN_CompanyName",
"ecrs"."StockInventoryLocal"."SIL_VEN_FK_Default",
"ecrs"."ReceiveWorksheet"."RCW_VEN_FK"
FROM ( "ecrs"."Vendor" JOIN "ecrs"."StockInventoryLocal" As "DefaultVendor" ON "ecrs"."Vendor"."VEN_PK" = "ecrs"."StockInventoryLocal"."SIL_VEN_FK_Default" ) JOIN "ecrs"."ReceiveWorksheet" As "WorksheetVendor"  ON "ecrs"."Vendor"."VEN_PK" = "ecrs"."ReceiveWorksheet"."RCW_VEN_FK"
```

I tried the above and received an error "Table 'DefaultVendor' not found."

Comment: I know nothing special about sybase but in databases you can alias your tables during query which means you can use the same table multiple times by just aliasing each instance to a separate name. The syntax should be something like `vendor AS vendor1` and `vendor AS vendord2`.

Comment: I tried that, but how do I pull from the different tables for the different alias' in the from statement?

Comment: You use `vendor1` and `vendor2` exactly as table names, you can use them everywhere you would have used a table name. Only after having defined them of course (that is after `vendor AS vendor1` and `vendor AS vendor2`) . If Sybase supports them, "Common Table Expressions" could help you too maybe.

Comment: Also try to put here a smaller example showing your problem because your current one if far too big to parse for someone not having the context and the details of your business case.

Comment: Updated the post with a smaller example and am getting the same error I was getting before.

Comment: Updated to reflect quotes on all the alias'.

Comment: This `"ecrs"."Vendor"."VEN_Code" As "DefaultVendor"` is an alias for a column and not a table...

Comment: Ah!  Thanks, Patrick.  So I need to declare the aliases in the FROM statement.  Going to try that now.

Comment: Tried that suggestion and am getting error "Correlation Name 'StockInventoryLocal' not found".

Comment: While I've posted an answer (with a few assumptions and a bit of confusion), it would probably help clear things up if you were to provide a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), in particular, provide some sample (raw) data and the desired results of joining said (raw) data

Comment: You might this link to the sql anywhere documentation about using correlation names helpful: http://dcx.sap.com/index.html#sa160/en/dbusage/kj-multiple-fks-joinsasp.html*d5e27117

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `ecrs` is a user/schema, and keeping in mind I'm not quite following the textual description (eg, not sure which column(s) from the `Vendor` table you're trying to display twice), see if the following gets you started ... we can tweak based on your feedback:

```
SELECT v.VEN_Code,
       v.VEN_CompanyName,
       sil.SIL_VEN_FK_Default,
       rcw.RCW_VEN_FK

FROM   ecrs.Vendor v

JOIN   ecrs.StockInventoryLocal sil
ON     v.VEN_PK = sil.SIL_VEN_FK_Default

JOIN   ecrs.ReceiveWorksheet rcw
ON     v.VEN_PK = rcw.RCW_VEN_FK
```

---

I'm assuming this isn't really what you want since you mention wanting to pull different vendors, ie, `v.VEN_PK` = `sil.SIL_VEN_FK_Default` = `rcw.RCW_VEN_FK` (all the same vendor).

If `sil.SIL_VEN_FK_Default` and `rcw.RCW_VEN_FK` are different values, then we'll need two references to `ecrs.Vendor`, but then I don't understand what the relationship is between `StockInventoryLocal` and `ReceiveWorksheet`.

In other words, let's say we join `Vendor`(#1) with `StockInventoryLocal`, and we join `Vendor`(#2) with `ReceiveWorksheet`, how do we join these two sets of joins to each other (eg, is there a relationship between `StockInventoryLocal` and `ReceiveWorksheet`? is there a relationship berween the two `Vendors`?)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, markp., even though it was directly applicable to the situation it was helpful!  I made a bunch of adjustments and it's now working, I want to upvote your answer but don't have enough points :(.

Comment: yeah, didn't think it would be a perfect answer as we were missing a few details; as for the upvoting ... no problem ... though you should be able to accept the answer (if appropriate); regards